Error Changing Tittle Color Swift | Sendbird
I am trying to change the color of my title on my custom sendbird navigation bar on my swift ui project to white from black but after trying everything I cannot get it done. I don't know if this is an issue of me overwriting pieces of code. Any Help much appreciated, thank you!
 class CustomViewController: UIViewController {
            var userId: String?
            var hostId: String?
            
            ...
            
            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
                // Add the channel list view controller as a child
                addChild(channelListVC)
                view.addSubview(channelListVC.view)
                channelListVC.view.frame = view.bounds
                channelListVC.didMove(toParent: self)
                title = "Messages"
                
                let skyBlueUIColor1 = UIColor(skyBlueColor.skyBlue)
                // Hide the back button
                navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleNewChannel(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name("NewChannelCreated"), object: nil)
                
                
                if let navigationBar = navigationController?.navigationBar {
                    let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
                    appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
                    appearance.backgroundColor = skyBlueUIColor1
                    appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
                    appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]

                    navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
                    navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
                    navigationBar.compactAppearance = appearance

                    navigationBar.tintColor = .white
                }

                // Enable large titles
                navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
                navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
            }

I tried many different ways of fixing this weird issue but still can't get it done.sendbird user messages with custom nav bar

UINavigationBarAppearance() should be called way before. I guess you view is already in window when called, no?

Yup, my 'UINavigationBarAppearance' is called when view is already, maybe too late in the lifecycle. I will try to call it earlier. But I remember also trying to initialize sendbird in the main file with the custom 'UINavigationBarAppearance' but the color was still black for the title. Maybe this is not the solution.
